# Getting user selection from drop down list

Tags: apex

I would like to get what the user has selected from a drop down list and pass that into a controller. I thought using the line below would get the user selected option but it just shows the label on my component:

```
var cmp = cmp.find('aura:id).get('v.label');

<lightning:select name="selectItem" label="Select an item"  aura:id="test" onchange="{!c.test}">
   <option value="">choose one...</option>
   <option value="1">one</option>
   <option value="2">two</option>
</lightning:select>
```

So I would like 1 of the options i.e 'one' to be stored in a variable. However, the code above just shows the label on the lightning select i.e. 'Select an item'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you have to fetch value instead of label i.e.

```
var cmp = cmp.find('test').get('v.value');
```

For more reference please have a look to salesforce [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm).